# Регулярка для пробела

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Имеется проверка на наличие кириллицы в логине:

```
if (!preg_match("/[а-я]+/i", $_POST['Login'])) {
  /* норм */
} else {
  /* не норм */
}
```

Как добавить проверку на наличие пробела?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\s
```

соответствует любому пробельному символу (пробел, табуляция, новая строка, перевод формата и т. д.)

Comment: Благодарю, правда уже успел найти друге решение проблемы:  

    preg_match("/[a-zA-Z_0-9]+/", $_POST['Login'])

Answer (score 0):

У вас логика не верна, наоборот надо вот:

```
if (!preg_match("/[а-я ]+/i", $_POST['Login'])) {
  /*  не норм */
} else {
  /* норм */
}
```

и для юникода u добавьте

Answer (score 0):

Ващет так.

```
if ( preg_match('/[а-я\s]+/i', $_POST['Login']) ) {
  /* норм */
} else {
  /* не норм */
}
```